# How to save embeds_many relation in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

```
class Hotel
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, type: String

  embeds_many :comments
end

class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :text, type: String

  belongs_to :hotel

  validates :text, presence: true
end

h = Hotel.create('hotel') 

   => <#Hotel _id: 52d68dd47361731d8b000000, title: "hotel">

c = Comment.new(text: 'text')

   => <#Comment _id: 52d68f3d7361731d8b040000, text: "text", hotel_id: nil>

h.comments << c

   => [#<Comment _id: 52d68f3d7361731d8b040000, text: "text", hotel_id: nil>]
h.save

   => true
Hotel.last.comments

   => []
```

variant 2

```
h.comments << Comment.new(text: 'new', hotel_id: h.id)

   => [<#Comment _id: 52d68f3d7361731d8b040000, text: "text", hotel_id: nil>, <#Comment _id: 52d691e17361731d8b050000, text: "new", hotel_id: BSON::ObjectId('52d68dd47361731d8b000000')>]

h.save

   => true
Hotel.last.comments

   => []
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two possible problems:

1. `Hotel.last` is not necessarily `Hotel` 52d68dd47361731d8b000000. You should look at `h.comments` or to be paranoid, `h.reload` and `h.comments`.
2. Your associations are confused.

From the [fine manual](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many):

> **Embedded 1-n**
>
> One to many relationships where the children are embedded in the
>   parent document are defined using Mongoid's `embeds_many` and
>   `embedded_in` macros.
>
> **Defining**
>
> The parent document of the relation should use the `embeds_many` macro
>   to indicate it has n number of embedded children, where the document
>   that is embedded uses `embedded_in`.

So your relation should be defined like this:

```
class Hotel
  embeds_many :comments
end

class Comment
  embedded_in :hotel
end
```

You're using `belongs_to: hotel` in `Comment` when you should say `embedded_in :hotel`.

The docs also say that:

> *Definitions are required on both sides to the relation in order for it to work properly.*

and your relation is incorrectly configured on one side so it won't work properly.